# In Rails models; for symbols get automatically converted to YAML when saving to DB. What is the correct approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, symbols

In my model example Game, has a status column. But I usually set status by using symbols. Example

```
self.status = :active
```

```
    MATCH_STATUS = { 
      :betting_on => "Betting is on",
      :home_team_won => "Home team has won",
      :visiting_team_won => "Visiting team has one",
      :game_tie => "Game is tied"
    }.freeze

def viewable_status
  MATCH_STATUS[self.status]
end
```

I use the above Map to switch between viewable status and viceversa.

However when the data gets saved to db, ActiveRecord appends "--- " to each status. So when I retrieve back the status is screwed.

What should be the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the getter and the setter:

```
def status
  read_attribute(:status).to_sym
end

def status=(new_status)
  write_attribute :status, new_status.to_s
end
```

Comment: Why is this not the default for symbols?

Comment: My guess is that's because if they were serialized as strings, then on deserialization there would be no way to tell what's being deserialized - a string or a symbol.