# What is a good strategy for symbols that might have spaces in them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to turn usernames into symbols before they are saved in my database, this seems logical since that username will be referred to often and we want to conserve on memory.  But what's a good option to substitute into the string in place of any spaces or other illegal characters?  Or should  it be kept a string to avoid the trouble?

Comment: Please explain how you turn a username into a symbol and how a symbol could have a space in it. It's all a bit *unclear*

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization... and it won't work ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep it as a string, avoid the trouble.

Worrying about this kind of thing is what's called Premature Optimization. And besides, a username is unlikely to be shared between users, so you wouldn't be conserving much memory regardless.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming. - Knuth

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must have spaces in your symbols, Ruby will let you do that:

```
foo = :"symbol with spaces" # => :"symbol with spaces"

foo.inspect # => ":\"symbol with spaces\""
```

Comment: This *is* the real answer, but I also agree that you should avoid using it at all costs.

Comment: @zeletic..how will symbols be stored in database...Will they be returned as symbol when retreived by a query? When I tried this `Market.create(:name => :Test)`,`Market.find(17).name`, I got this `"--- :Test\n"`

Comment: ActiveRecord serializes `Symbol`s to YAML when writing to the database, but does not deserialize when reading. There's a simple fix for this in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817145/in-rails-models-for-symbols-get-automatically-converted-to-yaml-when-saving-to-d. Or better yet, don't write `Symbol`s to the DB in the first place :)

Comment: Agree, symbols have not to be in a DB! What's wrong with usernames as strings?